# NodeJS date is different on Cloud Server vs Local

Tags: node.js, date, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Cloud for NodeJS applications (new to this). I use node to scrape dates from a website and then create date objects like so

```
var date = new Date("06/08/2016");
```

When I run the app on my local server the date is correct. When I push it to Google Cloud the date is one day behind. Does anyone have any insight into why this might be happening? I scrape the date as text in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: ... time zones? You're not indicating one, so the date is going to be resolved "however that instance of Node understands local time". If you want precision, build your date object off of a UTC time. And make sure all your clocks are set correctly (or, better, synced to some NTP server)

Comment: Yep timezones; website localisation might also come as a factor.  If your servers are in Europe the website may trigger some localisation string processing based on IPs location and give you DD/MM/YYYY dates

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Creating the date object using "06/08/2016" should still create it with that date right? Instead of showing up as "06/07/2016" when I run the app in the cloud?

Comment: Not really - you don't say where on the planet that time is supposed to happen, so the date parse interprets it as UTC, and then when you ask Node to tell you which day that is, locally, it can show you a different date entirely due to the timezone difference. It's why Date has `toString`, `toLocaleString`, `toGMTString`, `toISOString` *and* `toUTCString`. Basically when you try to print the "date" corresponding to the unix timestamp that is used under the hood, the actual date can differ *based on the timezone* you ask it to be interpreted in. Be explicit.

Comment: when you check new Date("06/08/2016") it may set
Wed Jun 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time). In my case time zone on server was different and shifted by 2h so 00:00:00 - 2h may give you the day before at 22:00:00. Check hours and minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone of your server is probably different than your time zone. You can check by checking the Date object via `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()`

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnDawyers no problem! Not sure why the other people posted as comments haha, they sound like solutions to me